# Where does Android Studio store my compiled application?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I'm doing a practice application in which I do a CRUD in android studio 3.0.1 and I'm running the application directly on my cell phone.

The application works without any inconvenience but when I want to remove the BD in SQlite from the application to analyze the fields from my pc I can not find the directory associated with my application

[image]

And checked the memory of the cell where all the applications are and I can not find the folder associated with it.

[image]

Could you tell me if it is stored in some hidden directory or something, because I can not find the folder associated with my application?

Note: I also have an external memory in my cell phone which has been reviewed folder by folder but nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And checked the memory of the cell where all the applications are and I can not find the folder associated with it.

You are looking at [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Your app will not have a directory there, unless you create one in your code.

> Could you tell me if it is stored in some hidden directory or something

Your APK is not stored anywhere that a user can see, except perhaps on a rooted device.

> I also have an external memory in my cell phone which has been reviewed folder by folder but nothing

That is [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).  Your app will not have a directory there, unless you create one in your code.